# Pycharm & Django: ImportError: No module named 'local_settings'

Tags: python, django, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

## in Jupyter notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook.I can run my script when I start jupyter notebook from this command.

```
python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

The python version is
3.5.0 (default, Sep 14 2016, 05:13:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)]
It's works fine.

## in Pycherm with Jupyter notebook

Now I want to use jupyter in Pycharm.

```
import os, sys
import dateutil.parser
import django
MYPROJECT = 'django/project/path'
sys.path.insert(0, MYPROJECT)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local_settings.py")
django.setup()
```

This python version is also 3.5.0 (default, Sep 14 2016, 05:13:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)]

So I think this is different problem with [Django cannot import LOCAL settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904209/django-cannot-import-local-settings)

I got this error in pycherm jupyter. Why I got "ImportError: No module named 'local_settings'"?
If you know how to solve this problem. Please help me!!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d97420db067c> in <module>()
      7 sys.path.insert(0, MYPROJECT)
      8 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local_settings.py")
----> 9 django.setup()
     10 from django.conf import settings
     11 import main.management.commands.mws as mws

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py in setup(set_prefix)
     17     from django.utils.log import configure_logging
     18 
---> 19     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
     20     if set_prefix:
     21         set_script_prefix(

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     54         """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
     55         if self._wrapped is empty:
---> 56             self._setup(name)
     57         val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
     58         self.__dict__[name] = val

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in _setup(self, name)
     41                 % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
     42 
---> 43         self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
     44 
     45     def __repr__(self):

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in __init__(self, settings_module)
    104         self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module
    105 
--> 106         mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    107 
    108         tuple_settings = (

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ImportError: No module named 'local_settings.py'; 'local_settings' is not a package
```

## what I tried

I add this lines on settings.py

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

My local_settigns is this.

```
from .settings import *

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

But I got this error.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-93d2cfaa1e85> in <module>()
      8 sys.path.insert(0, MYPROJECT)
      9 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "local_settings.py")
---> 10 django.setup()
     11 from django.conf import settings
     12 import main.management.commands.mws as mws

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py in setup(set_prefix)
     17     from django.utils.log import configure_logging
     18 
---> 19     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
     20     if set_prefix:
     21         set_script_prefix(

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, name)
     54         """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
     55         if self._wrapped is empty:
---> 56             self._setup(name)
     57         val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
     58         self.__dict__[name] = val

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in _setup(self, name)
     41                 % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
     42 
---> 43         self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
     44 
     45     def __repr__(self):

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py in __init__(self, settings_module)
    104         self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module
    105 
--> 106         mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    107 
    108         tuple_settings = (

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    124                 break
    125             level += 1
--> 126     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    127 
    128 

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

/Users/trmt_8/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ImportError: No module named 'local_settings.py'; 'local_settings' is not a package
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django cannot import LOCAL settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904209/django-cannot-import-local-settings)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by this code. just run at top on the script.

```
import os, sys, django
sys.path.append('/my/project/path')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings') #if you have local_settings.py it's all so works well.
django.setup()
```

Maybe the problem comes from
`sys.path.insert(0, MYPROJECT)`.